# How do I prevent a window from closing?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, windowlistener

first sorry for my bad english.

Hi, i'm trying to use a confirmDialog with a YES_NO_OPTION.
what i want is that when i close a frame a confimDialog will be displayed asking me if want to close.

if i press yes everyThing most be closed, if i press no the confirmDialog will disapear

but the problem is even if i press no button the frame close this is my code:

```
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("2D Game");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(1600,600);
frame.setResizable(false);

    private void continuerButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_continuerButtonActionPerformed
        int level=getlevel();
        System.out.println(niveau);
        if(niveau == 1)
        {
            this.dispose();
            frame.add(new Board());
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
            {
                doExitOption();
            }
            });
        }
    }
```

and this is `doExitOption` methode:

```
 public void doExitOption()
    {
        int option=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "do you want to quit the game",    "Warnning",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                frame.dispose();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/). It can manager the default close operation for you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the `JFrame`'s default close operation so that your call to `dispose` is the only call being made to dispose the window:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Default closing of JFrame to `DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` .